# Power Automate - Send email 30 days after date - Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, send-email, syntax

I have a Document Library (SP Online) in which users Upload documents, then they Modify the new File to add its properties.  The user sets a Date column - "Published Date" manually after Uploading.  I need a Reminder email to send 30 days after the Published Date.  So my trigger should be when a File is Modified.  My thought was to create a second Date Column (Email Date), and have Power Automate Update the File Properties.  The problem is that I don't have the Syntax right, and it doesn't ONLY update the file properties of the recently Modified File.  Rather, it updates every file in the Library.  I'd like that Email Date column to basically equal the Published Date + 30 days, then I'd have it send an email on that Date.  This should apply only the the Modified File, rather than all of them that exist in the Library.  But I'm not setting this up correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here're steps:

1.Create a calculated column return data type as date and time, formula:=[Published Date]+30

2.Create a flow as following picture shows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  So after creating that calculated column, my condition basically says "If Today = Email Date, Send an email"?

Comment: Yes, if Today = Email Date, it will send an email.

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly